# Oracle error while executing query : ORA-00905: Missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00905

While executing the below code:

```
select distinct tam.sol_id||'|'||(select sol.sol_desc from sol where sol.sol_id=tam.sol_id)||'|'||count(*)||'|'||sum(org_tran_amt)
||'|'||count(case when ott.tran_date between '01-02-2021' and '24-02-2021' as 1 else 0 end) a
from ott,tam
where tam.acid=ott.acid
and tam.gl_sub_head_code in ('85300','85320','85330','85340','85350','85360','85365','85370','85380','85390','85395')
and tran_date <= '24-02-2021'
and tam.sol_id in (select sst.sol_id from sst where sst.set_id='ROFPZ')
and not exists (select * from tct where tct.tran_date=ott.tran_date and trim(tct.tran_id)=trim(ott.tran_id)
and nvl(ott.org_tran_amt-tct.AMT_OFFSET,0)='0' and tct.entity_cre_flg='Y' and tct.del_flg='N');
```

received below error message as output:

```
from ott,tam
           *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

Comment: The error message doesn't match your query (tam vs gam).

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  Don't use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify the case part of the statement:

```
case when ott.tran_date between '01-02-2021' and '24-02-2021' then 1 else 0 end
```

You must write "then" instead of "as".

Comment: Thanks, but output is not desirous 
855|JAL|3|4500|3
843|KOT|4|3400|4
Last column has to be 0 or less than other values but giving same output

Comment: Try to use sum instead of count.